# Error: expected a declaration

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, access-specifier

So far all I have in my `DecisionTree.h` file is

```
namespace DecisionTree
{
     public static double Entropy(int pos, int neg);
}
```

and Visual Studio is already highlighting the `public` and saying

> Error: expected a declaration.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`public` is an access specifier. Access specifiers are applicable only within `class/struct` body and not inside `namespace`. In C++ (unlike Java) it must be followed by a colon `:` inside the `class` body.

For example,

```
class DecisionTree {  // <----- 'class' (not 'namespace')
public:  // <------ access specifier
  static double Entropy (int pos, int neg);
private:
  int i;
};
```

Comment: @Daniel, also when using access specifier for inheritance you don't need `:`. You may also want to learn about default access specifiers for `class` and `struct` are `private` and `public` respectively (unlike default scope in Java).

Comment: If I don't want to put the function in a class? how should I write it?

Comment: @STF, in such case you may put that function simply in an open space (i.e. under no scope) OR put it inside a `namespace` as suggested in the Qn. But you cannot have any access specifier associated with it once the function is outside a class.

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely give an error, for you dint declared any class,struct, or enum and directly you have written a static function inside a namespace. So, first write a class definition inside a namespace and then a function.